# Deleting a string from another string c#

Tags: c#, string

I want to subtract an inputted string from another inputted string, however the operator "-" is not allowed with strings.
Example

```
s1 = "abcdhello";
s2 = "hellothere";
//i want s3 to be like:
s3 = "abcd";
```

How can i achieve this, i tried .substring, but it didn't work out.

Update:
Let's say i have a key and text, let's consider s1 as a combinedkey, and s2 as the text, i want to get the uncombinedkey.

Comment: What’s your business rule here?  Do you have to ‘subtract’ any string that gets repeated ??

Comment: are you just worried about the letters? do you want to find sequences? please update your question or have it closed due to being unclear

Comment: _i want s3 to be like: s3 = "abcd";_ - `s1.Substring(0,4);`

Comment: The terminology you use for *text* is still ambiguous, so are you saying the *text* in the *combined key* may only be a **subset** of the *text* in `s2`

Comment: `s1` doesn't not contain `s2` in your example, what are the rules here? Do you want it to try every combination (in a reduction loop) of `s2` until it finds something to remove from the end of `s1`?

Comment: Why only `hello` to be removed?

Answer (score 1):

loop through `s1` and `s2` finding the longest overlap and returning the difference, or the original value

```
public static string GetWeird(string s1, string s2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s1);
    for (int i = Math.Max(0, s1.Length - s2.Length); i < s1.Length; i++)
    {
        var ss1 = s1.Substring(i, s1.Length - i);
        var ss2 = s2.Substring(0, Math.Min(s2.Length, ss1.Length));
        Console.WriteLine(ss2.PadLeft(s1.Length));
        if (ss1 == ss2)
            return s1.Substring(0, i);
    }

    return s1;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var s1 = "5675675756756abcdhello";
    var s2 = "hellothere";
    var s3 = GetWeird(s1, s2);
    Console.WriteLine(s3);
}
```

**Output**

```
5675675756756abcdhello
            hellothere
             hellother
              hellothe
               helloth
                hellot
                 hello
5675675756756abcd
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/VcJMoX)

Comment: You prefer the shortest overlap, which is surprising. And there is also an exception, zero overlap is the least preferred. And when zero overlap is the only overlap, you return null, not the original string. It is really weird.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek thanks updated because of your concerns

Answer (score 1):

Convert both strings to lists of chars and remove chars in the first list if they are in the second.

As simple as that

```
string s1 = "abcdefg";
string s2 = "efghijk";

List<char> s1l = s1.ToList();
List<char> s2l = s2.ToList();

s1l.RemoveAll(c => s2l.ToList().Exists(n => n == c));

string s3 = String.Concat(s1l);
```